# What is the difference between axios and expressjs

Tags: sql, express, axios, backend

I've been trying to get better at understanding back end but can't seem to understand. At my job I write mostly React. I've been trying to learn the backend but am struggling to understand it. Our company uses epxressjs to with this
`router.get("/getExample", async function (req, res) )`  with a SQL query inside it.
Then in a different file uses axios and has

```
export async function getExample() {
  let dataReturn = "";
  await axios.get(`${linkUrl}getExample`).then((result) => {
    if (!result.data.sqlData[0]) {
      dataReturn = "ERROR SQL Data was not returned";
    } else {
      dataReturn = result.data.sqlData;
    }
  });
  return dataReturn;
}
```

I guess I am just confused. Do you need to use express and axios together to make a backend? Videos on youtube talk about making API's with Express and Axios but never used together.

Answer (score 0):

Express and Axios are two different tools that serve different purposes in a web application. Express is a Node.js web application framework used for creating server-side applications, whereas Axios is a library used for making HTTP requests from client-side applications.

In the code you provided, the Express application is serving an HTTP GET request to the "/getExample" endpoint, which then executes a SQL query and returns the result to the client. Axios is then used in the client-side code to make an HTTP GET request to the same endpoint and retrieve the data returned by the SQL query.

Comment: that would mean that his code is for client side and can respond to http requests